# Pushing a 2d array onto a C++ STL stack?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stack, 2d

```
int test[5][5];
stack<int**> mystack;
mystack.push(test);
```

I get the error:

> no matching function for call to ‘std::stack > >::push(int [5][5])’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_stack.h:182: note: candidates are: void std::stack<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const typename _Sequence::value_type&) [with _Tp = int**, _Sequence = std::deque >]

I've never really used stacks before so I would appreciate any help. If I declare test as a one-dimensional array and stack as int*, it works fine.

Edit: I'm trying to implement backtracing for a sudokusolver. I have the sudoku grid as a 9x9 array of set objects (objects that hold the solution or possible solutions). I have to push the current state of the puzzle onto the stack, and then from there try guess and check. If a guess creates a contradiction (ie violates the rules of a sudoku), then I would pop from the stack to recover the puzzle before the invalid guess.

Comment: If `boost::array` or `std::array` in C++0x is allowed, you can use
`stack< array< array< int, 5 >, 5 > >` for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

An `int **` is not the same as a 2D array. A pointer to `int test[5][5]` would be `int (*)[5]`, so you need a `stack<int (*)[5]>`. There's a good explanation of this here: [Arrays and pointers in C](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html).

Comment: @kevin: You can't push an array itself, only a pointer to it. It doesn't matter most of the time, because you can use the pointer in the same way as you would use the array itself.

Comment: @etarion: The OP added that requirement only now, but the fact remains that you can't push an array directly. @Johnsyweb's solution of using a vector would be better in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `test` is **not** of type `int**`.

If you want a two-dimensional array, I would recommend using `std::vector`. This would certainly save your confusion with arrays and pointers...

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > two_d_vector;
two_d_vector test;
stack<two_d_vector> mystack;
mystack.push(test);
```

Comment: Just made an edit to my original post, I need to have first in last out.

Comment: Stacks are *usually* described as Last In First Out but, yes, the first element you `push` shall be the last you `pop`.